# Load textBox Form title on load

Tags: c#

I want to show current form Title inside the textBox
But the code below doesnt do it,it only works if I set it on Button1_click.
And After clicking the button it will change to the form title
But I need it to set the form title in the textbox instantly on load

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ShowTitle
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process currentp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        textBox1.Text = currentp.MainWindowTitle;


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to use the Form_Shown event instead

Comment: add this code after `InitializeComponent`

Comment: Did        `private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process currentp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            textBox1.Text = currentp.MainWindowTitle;
        }` And no difference

Comment: Added it after InitializeComponent and no difference too.

Comment: That's strange because when Form1_Shown is called the MainWindow is available and you could read it. Are you sure the event code is executed?

Comment: That is what I got at the moment
`public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Process currentp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            textBox1.Text = currentp.MainWindowTitle;
        }`

But it still doesnt change the textbox text to the form title

Answer (score 1):

This simple code demonstrate that when your event handler for Form.Load event is called there is no MainWindowTitle to read from the `currentp`, while if you execute the same code in the Form.Shown event handler there is a MainWindowTitle in the currentp variable

```
Form f;
TextBox t;
void Main()
{
    f = new Form();
    f.Text = "This is a test";
    t = new TextBox();
    f.Controls.Add(t);
    f.Load += onLoad;
    f.Shown += onShow;
    f.Show();
}
void onLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process currentp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentp.MainWindowTitle))
        t.Text = currentp.MainWindowTitle;
    else
        t.Text = "NO TITLE";
}

void onShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Uncomment these line to see the differences
    // if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentp.MainWindowTitle))
    //     t.Text = currentp.MainWindowTitle;
    // else
    //     t.Text = "NO TITLE";
}
```

Comment: upvoted because Shown event works. not sure why not for OP. any way another test i did was to make Load event async and then `await Task.Delay(10)` before creating process that actually worked too.

Comment: Yes that should work as well with this simple scenario, but I am a bit uncertain if it is a good idea to make Form_Load async. Too many underlying processes are at work in the sequence of events that leads to a form shown on screen and it is too easy to mess with them at that point in time.

Comment: oh. yes that was just a test and definitely OP must use `Shown` event. i just wanted to make sure that some parts of form is not created at that time.